# Shell script to validate csv fields

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a csv file with 20 fields. I want to have a script to check if the file is valid according with the following points:

- It needs to have 20 fields separated by pipes.
- Each of the 20 fields should match a regex.
- Know the line and field number for any regex unmatch.

ex:

```
f1|f2|f3|...|f20
1|aaaa|Y|...|2014/06/25
2|bb|Y...|2014/06/25
3|ccc|N...|2014/06/25

regex:
f1 [0-9]
f2 [a-z]{2,4}
f3 [YN]
.
.
.
f20 [1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]
```

What are the best shell tools to do it? Do you have any similar script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best tool in Unix systems is `awk` for this job. You can use an awk command like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NF!=20{print "not enough fields"; exit}
!($1~/^[0-9]$/) {print "1st field invalid"; exit}' file.csv
```

Comment: that is a good solution! thanks, but I need to know also if some field isn't matching it and the line and the fields number.

Comment: Sure that can also be done using ask. Rather than using `&&` to check multiple fields you can have individual field checks and separate handlers.  Start writing your ask command and let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: I'm not getting how can it be done to check two or more fields.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a perl script for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @regexes = (
    qr/\d/,                  # regex quotes qr/ /
    qr/[a-z]{2,4}/, 
    qr/[YN]/,
    #etc. put the rest of the regexes here
);

while (<>) {                 # loop through every line of file
    my @fields = split /\|/; # split on pipe, needs escaping
    if (@fields != 20) {
        print "incorrect number of fields on line $.\n";
        exit;
    }
    for my $f (0..$#fields) { # loop through all fields
        unless ($fields[$f] =~ $regexes[$f]) { # regex match
            print "invalid field on line $., field ", ($f+1), "\n";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

If you save the script as `valid.pl` and make it executable `chmod +x valid.pl`, you can call it like `./valid.pl filename`. Currently the script will exit as soon as the first problem is encountered. If you remove the `exit` statements, it will list all of the problems with the file.

In case you're unfamiliar with perl, `$.` is a special variable which contains the line number in the `while` loop. `$#fields` is the value of the last index of the array `@fields`, so `0..$#fields` is equivalent to the list 0,1,...,19. Array indices start at 0, so I've added 1 to the field number.

Comment: +1: Though the `$line` can be avoided by using `$.` directly and you'll need to add one to `$f` since indices starts at 0.

Comment: @jaypal thanks. I assigned `$.` to a variable to hopefully make the code a little clearer to someone unfamiliar with perl, although I agree that it is redundant. Also agreed about the field number, will edit.